# Kubernetes private docker registry - registry proxy doesn't work

Tags: kubernetes, docker-registry

I'm running Kubernetes on a 3 node setup (Core OS - setup from this guide - https://coreos.com/kubernetes/docs/latest/deploy-master.html). I need to run a private docker registry in the setup, so I was following this guide: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/cluster/addons/registry

I think that the registry pod is running, at least there is an empty response from the registry pod on port 5000 (the guide says I should be getting a "404 Unauthorized" response). I'm testing this from a busybox, it even works with the dns hostname.

But the main problem is that the kube-registry-proxy won't run properly. I was able to get the proxies up and running by adding the definition yaml in the /etc/kubernetes/manifest/ folder on each node. When I list the pods from the kube-system namespace, I see this:

```
kube-registry-proxy-192.168.10.4       1/1       Running   0          32m
kube-registry-proxy-192.168.10.5       1/1       Running   0          3d
kube-registry-proxy-192.168.10.6       1/1       Running   0          1d
```

That seems to be working fine. But when I ssh into any node of the Kube cluster, and try tu run

```
curl -v localhost:5000
```

I'm getting this error:

```
* Rebuilt URL to: localhost:5000/
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* connect to 127.0.0.1 port 5000 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to localhost port 5000: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 5000: Connection refused
```

Also, when I run

```
sudo lsof -i|grep LISTEN
```

there is no port 5000 listed. Any clues?

EDIT: What I need is to be able to push and pull images from within kubernetes (so the pods ca use images from there) and also to be able to push images from outside (using the port forwarding method for port 5000 is sufficient, but other options are welcome too)

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not listening on your `localhost`. If you are only interested in testing internal cluster traffic from any node within the cluster, you can curl the pod's IP or the service cluster IP:

```
$ kubectl get po <your_pod> -o yaml | grep -i podip
    podIP: <spod_private_ip>
$ curl <pod_private_ip>:5000
$ kubectl get svc <your_svc> -o yaml | grep -i -w 'clusterip\|port'
     clusterIP: <cluster_ip>
     port: 5000
$ curl <cluster_ip>:5000
```

To expose your service to external traffic, you will need to specify either the `NodePort` or `LoadBalancer` service type as seen in this K8s [example](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/connecting-applications/).

Comment: I don't need to expose anything, I just need to be able to push and pull images from within kubernetes and maybe push and pull from outside, but it would be sufficient if it would be working as described in the guide. But if there is a better guide somewhere (wasn't able to google it, I can use it, I just need some clues on how to make it work)

Comment: Have you tried with your service's cluster IP as I mentioned? Note that that will work only from within your cluster.

Comment: Yes, as written in the question: "I think that the registry pod is running, at least there is an empty response from the registry pod on port 5000 (the guide says I should be getting a "404 Unauthorized" response). I'm testing this from a busybox, it even works with the dns hostname." But I also need to push some base images from outside the cluster into the registry.

Comment: meaning - it probably works from within the cluster, I just didn't tested anything else except a curl call from within the cluster, because I need to get an image from outside into the registry

Comment: Regarding the service exposure to the outside, I'm not sure whether it will be so easy - will I be able to access the registry using the same domain name from inside and from outside? I think the reason why the guide is written using the registry proxy containers is quite simple - I would be able to access the repo from inside and outside of the cluster using the same hostname - localhost:5000

Comment: No, you won't be able to use localhost as your domain name for both internal and external traffic.

Comment: regarding the guide, I would be able to do it because of the port forwarding from kubectl proxy

Comment: I'm having this same problem.  The reason the guide does this `localhost` trick is to get around the problem of `docker` complaining about an insecure registry.  `localhost` is automatically "secure" so nodes in the cluster really need to pull from `localhost`.